# Running multiple specs with mock data: Karma, Jasmine, and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have over 10 Jasmine specs that I need to run with Karma (FKA Testacular). From the examples that I've seen, people have one Karma config file that contains all of their assets and all of their specs:

```
'src/**/*.js',
'test/unit/**/*.spec.js'
```

This doesn't seem like a problem, but I run into an issue because each of the specs have their own set of mock data in a separate file (to mock the response from ajax requests), and I fear that some of the data in the mocks may conflict with one another.

This leads me to think that I am missing something, or doing something wrong. How can I run multiple specs that have their own mocked ajax responses with Karma test runner?

Perhaps my problem is that I am mocking the data in the wrong way?

Thanks!